# How relating two tables to show name row and not the id in mysql+pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo, innodb, relation

I don't know how show the name of the row in table 2 instead of his id when show it results of table 1.

Let me explain:

I have this tables in innoDB:

```
- PACIENTES(table name).
    * id  (int)
    * nombre (varchar)
    * apellido (varchar)
    * pais (varchar)
    * departamento (varchar)
    * ciudad (varchar)

- lista_paises(table name).
    * id  (int)
    * opcion (varchar)

- lista_departamento(table name).
    * id_departamento  (int)
    * opcion (varchar)
    * relacion (int)-----relation with table lista_paises----

- MUNICIPIOS(table name).
    * id_municipio  (int)
    * id_departamento (int)-----relation with table lista_departamento----
    * municipio_nombre (varchar)
```

in table pacientes I have save the id of lista_paises, lista_departamento, municipios like

----id----nombre-----apellido-----pais----departamento----ciudad

```
  1    Juan    Perez     10      178        198
```

and I need to show in the page

```
 id   nombre  apellido     pais        departamento        ciudad

  1    Juan    Perez     El Salvador      Santa Ana        Santa Ana
```

I have this sentence(the other sentence with departamento is the same) but not show the real departamento or the real ciudad...always show only one departamento or municipio with id 1

```
<?
    $sql = "SELECT PACIENTES.ciudad, MUNICIPIOS.municipio_nombre 
    FROM PACIENTES INNER JOIN MUNICIPIOS 
    ON MUNICIPIOS.id_departamento = PACIENTES.ciudad";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $municipio_nombre = $row['municipio_nombre'];
?>

<td><? echo $municipio_nombre ?></td>
```

I'm sorry if my question is so long or not understand very well but to be honest I don't know how explain better this question... I hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `nombre_municipio` in table and `MUNICIPIOS.municipio_nombre` in query.

Also `ON MUNICIPIOS.id_departamento = PACIENTES.ciudad` is comparing varchar with int

To Join `MUNICIPIOS` and `PACIENTES` you require to have field related to `PACIENTES.id` in `MUNICIPIOS`table eg (`MUNICIPIOS.id_pacientes`)

```
$sql = "SELECT PACIENTES.ciudad, MUNICIPIOS.municipio_nombre 
    FROM PACIENTES 
    INNER JOIN MUNICIPIOS 
    ON  PACIENTES.id = MUNICIPIOS.id_pacientes";
```

Comment: thank you @david, my mistake in nombre_municipio, I already change to municipio_nombre. with your sentence I have error in `= id`... I change it to ciudad..but always show me only the municipio_nombre with id 172 in all users

Comment: @asterix_jv changed answer with explanation

Comment: there is necesary to have related fields with table PACIENTES? can I union or join this tables even if there are not related or I can't?