# Show name row and not the id in DataTable Server Side

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable, server-side

I have two tables in the database(MySql) one is for the name of the countries and the another one is for the users. right now when some user is added into the site he/she choose from where he/she is..all is fine but since the user database growth into 2,000 users I need to force to change to server side datatable to show all the users without the script force to freeze the screen or the site. Now I can't see the name of the country of every user, just only the id...so my question what can need to add or change to see the country name and not the id.

I follow these posts:

1. [how-relating-two-tables-to-show-name-row-and-not-the-id-in-mysqlpdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262938/how-relating-two-tables-to-show-name-row-and-not-the-id-in-mysqlpdo)
2. [server-side](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysqli)

Here are my Databases:

```
|----------USERS-------------|
|---id-----------int---------|
|---nombres---varchar(150)---| is the user name
|---fnac-------datetime------| is the birthday
|---direccion----text--------| is the address
|---paisid--------int(3)-----| is the country id
|---foto-------varchar(50)---| is the user photo
|----------------------------|

|-----------PAISES-----------|
|---id---------int(11)-------| is the country id
|---paises---varchar(100)----| is the country name
|----------------------------|
```

Here my code (right now I don't use it because I don't know where I need to insert it):

```
<?php $query = "SELECT U.paisid, P.pais,
(SELECT pais FROM PAISES WHERE id = paisid)
AS pais
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN PAISES P
ON  U.paisid = P.id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );   
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $rows as $row )
{ ?><?php echo $row['pais']; ?><?php } ?>
```

The JS:

```
$('#userTabla').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
    "sAjaxSource": "includes/server_process.php",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nombres" },
        { "mData": "paisid" },
        {
            "mData": null,
            "sClass": "center",
            "sDefaultContent": "",
            "fnRender": function (o) {
            return '<a href="perfil.php?id=' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Ver perfil</a> <a href="editar.php?id=' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Editar</a> <a id="' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Borrar</a>'
        },
        "aTargets": [3]
        }
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ registros por pag"
    }
});
```

The server_process.php(part where I change the example data)

```
$aColumns = array( 'id', 'nombres', 'paisid');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "USERS";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "dbuser";
$gaSql['password']   = "XXXXXX";
$gaSql['db']         = "dbmega";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
$query = "SELECT USERS.* , PAISES.`paises` as countryName
FROM USERS 
INNER JOIN PAISES 
ON  paisid = id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );   
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

 $returnArray = array();
foreach( $rows as $row )
{ 
returnArray[] = array($row['id'],$row['nombres'],$row['countryName']);
}
```

**Please change paisid type to int**

```
var myDataTable = $('#userTabla').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12  center'p>>",
    "sAjaxSource": "includes/server_process.php",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "id" },
        { "mData": "nombres" },
        { "mData": "paisid" },
         {
           "mData": null,
           "sClass": "center",
           "sDefaultContent": "",
           "fnRender": function (o) {
           return '<a href="perfil.php?id=' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Ver perfil</a> <a href="editar.php?id=' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Editar</a> <a id="' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Borrar</a>'
         },
         "aTargets": [3]
        }
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ registros por pag"
    }
});

myDataTable.fnAddData( <? echo json_encode(returnArray[]); ?>);
```

Comment: Hi, @volkinc yes, that was write error, already is int(I will edit it right now the table)...but how can I show the name of the country and not the id when the dataTable server side show all the users in the table?

Comment: Hi. not enough data. What is o.aData[0]? what is perfil.php?

Comment: I Updated the answer , please have a look

Comment: Hi, ` o.aData[0]` is the id of every user catching in the server side(server_process.php). The `perfil.php?id= , editar.php?id=` are the every user profile page and user edit page.

Comment: and I think the select code is wrong... the U IS MISSED in this part = `FROM USERS 'HERE IS MISSING THE U'
INNER JOIN PAISES P
ON  U.paisid`...and the code I used is working but inside of js I can't insert any code because give me always SyntaxError: `Unexpected token <`